# Using malloc() for multiple inputs?

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-arrays, calloc, dynamic-allocation

Alright I know that `malloc` or `calloc` can be used for dynamic allocation but as a new to C I don't know how to use that memory I allocated for inputting multiple inputs like in example of TC++ we have this code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <alloc.h>
#include <process.h>

int main(void)
{
   char *str;

   /* allocate memory for string */
   if ((str = (char *) malloc(10)) == NULL)
   {
      printf("Not enough memory to allocate buffer\n");
      exit(1);  /* terminate program if out of memory */
   }

   /* copy "Hello" into string */
   strcpy(str, "Hello");
    /* display string */
    printf("String is %s\n", str);
    /* free memory */
   free(str);

   return 0;
}
```

In thus code we place Hello to memory we allocated now that should leave us with 4 more character spaces what we should do to add data to those spaces as well.

I want to implement this idea when the user is asked about number of inputs and he lets say 10 or 100 then the program inputs the data and stores them and print that data to screen.

Comment: so you want to allocate size according to the user input?

Comment: You probably are missing the `#include <stdlib.h>` directive. And if you want to fill partly some `malloc`-ed or `calloc`-ed dynamically allocated heap zone, you probably have to do some housekeeping e.g. with current and ending indexes or pointers. You might want to use `getline` to read entirely a `malloc`-ed line.

Comment: In C there is no need to cast the results of call to `malloc()`/`calloc()`. Also it is not recommended to do so, as this may hide errors, as most probably it is the case in your example (see *Basile*'s comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to append to your `malloc`ed string, use [strcat](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat)

```
str = malloc(20);
...
/* copy "Hello" into string */
strcpy(str, "Hello");
strcat(str, ", world!");
/* display string */
printf("String is %s\n", str); /* will print 'Hello, world!' */
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for "pointer arithmetic".
In you example, you are allocating 10 bytes of memory, and store the address of the first byte in the pointer `str`.
Then you copy the string `"hello"` to this memory, which leaves you 4 bytes you can use (because `"hello"` is 5 bytes + one byte for the string termination character `\0`).
If you want to store something in those remaining 4 bytes, you can just calculate the memory address with pointer arithmetic.
For example, if you want to access the 6'th byte from `str`, you do `str+5`. simple.
So, to extend your example, you can do:

```
strcpy(str, "Hello");
strcpy(str+5, " man");
```

and the output of `printf("String is %s\n", str);` would be `"Hello man"`.